# jquery images keep moving

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 images set up I want images 3 and 4 to slide down when I click on one of the images. And I want a div to come down from them. Sorry I must admit I am new to this so sorry if it is a dumb question but I have tried for hours and can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

IMAGE 1        IMAGE 2

IMAGE 3        IMAGE 4

when I click image 1 all of my images move to positions not wanted. When I click image 2 everything works as I want it to (images 3 and 4 slide down and my div comes down from images 1 and 2). Image 3 also works correctly. When I click Image 4 all of the images move correctly except for image 4 and it moves to a weird position.

**Here is my css** :

```
.image1{position:relative;top:-10px;left:-10px;margin:10px;}
.image2{position:relative;top:-10px;left:25%;margin:10px;}
.image3{position:relative;top:0px;left:-10px;margin:10px;}
.image4{position:relative;top:0px;left:25%;margin:10px;}

body{left:20%;width:60%;height:110%;padding:10px;
     background-color:white;position:absolute;
     margin:0px;opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=90);
      /* For IE8 and earlier */-webkit-box-shadow:  6px 6px 50px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     box-shadow:  6px 6px 50px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color:#0033ff;}

#panel,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4{
display:none;padding:400px;margin:auto;}

#panel,#flip,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4,#flip2,#flip3,#flip4{
padding:5px;text-align:center;background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;}
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
`enter code here`<img src = "pics/dog.jpg" id="flip" class ="image1"/>
<div id="panel">Hello world! test one</div>

<img src = "pics/dog.jpg" id="flip2" class ="image2"/>
 <div id="panel2">Hello world! test two</div>

<div id="panel3">Hello world! test three</div>
<img src = "pics/dog.jpg" id="flip3" class ="image3"/>

<div id="panel4">Hello world! test four</div>
<img src = "pics/dog.jpg" id="flip4" class ="image4" />
```

**Here is my Script:**

```
enter code here

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
  <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip2").click(function(){
    $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip3").click(function(){
    $("#panel3").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip4").click(function(){
    $("#panel4").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can use one ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can use only one script tag with one `ready()`. I think your problem is in your CSS. Here is a solution in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daM6h/1/), if I understood the problem correctly.